# Building a CriteriaBuilder query to compare lists

Tags: java, sql, jpa, criteria, criteria-api

How to compare the list from the database table and the list from the program code? 
The database has user profiles with skills.

```java
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "profile_skills",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "profile_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "skill_id", referencedColumnName="id"))
    private Map<Integer, Skill> skills = new TreeMap<>();
```

Need to find user profiles that have the right skills. 
I made a request, but he selects profiles that have at least one match for any of the skills in the list. However, I need to select only those that have all the skills indicated in the list (a match with all the elements in the list).

```java
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Profile> cq = cb.createQuery(Profile.class);
    Root<Profile> root  = cq.from(Profile.class);
    MapJoin<Profile, Integer, Skill> skillMapJoin = root.join(Profile_.skills);
    Expression<String> nameSkill = skillMapJoin.get(Skill_.name);

    List<String> skills = Arrays.asList("Java", "JavaScript");

    cq.where(nameSkill.in(skills)).groupBy(root.get(Profile_.id));

    TypedQuery<Profile> q = em.createQuery(cq);
    List<Profile> profiles = q.getResultList();
```

For instance:
Profile1.Skills : "Java", "Scala", "Groovy", "JavaScript"
Profile2.Skills : "Java", "Scala", "Groovy"
Profile3.Skills : "Groovy", "JavaScript"

My query returns the result: Profile1, Profile2, Profile3
There must be a result: Profile1

**Please tell me how to implement the request I need?**
**How to compare the list from the database table and the list from the program code?**
It is possible not only using CriteriaBuilder, but also other query options like sql or jpql.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, although I think it can be done differently.

```java
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Profile> cq = cb.createQuery(Profile.class);
    Root<Profile> root  = cq.from(Profile.class);
    MapJoin<Profile, Integer, Skill> skillMapJoin = root.join(Profile_.skills);
    Expression<String> nameSkill = skillMapJoin.get(Skill_.name);

    List<String> skills = Arrays.asList("Java", "JavaScript");
    Integer sizeListValue = skills.size();
    Expression<Long> countSkills = cb.count(exp);

    cq.where(nameSkill.in(skills))
      .groupBy(root.get(Profile_.id))
      .having(cb.equal(countSkills, sizeListValue));

    TypedQuery<Profile> q = em.createQuery(cq);
    List<Profile> profiles = q.getResultList();
```